# Нужен аналог функций из php в C# (выборка из БД)

Tags: c#, php, база-данных

на php есть кусок кода:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM table1";  
$result = mysql_query($query);  
while($line=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
{//вывод таблицы(в массиве line строка из БД)}
```

Нужен аналог кода на С#.
Кто-нибудь обладает необходимыми знаниями?

Comment: LINQ to SQL + lambda expressions. Копать в этом направлении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зависит от того, что вы хотите получить. Копать надо в сторону ADO.NET и LINQ to SQL.